# Mac app becomes smaller when copied to USB

Tags: macos, mac, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, digital-signature

I have a Mac app that is 443,245,675 bytes.

When I copy it to a flash drive, the copied version is only 443,239,527 bytes and the app package becomes invalid (`spctl -a` fails).

This difference (6148 bytes) is the size of a .DS_Store file exactly, but none seems to exist in the app package. My hidden files are visible and I've looked using `ls -l`—there's no .DS_Store file there.

What's going on here and how do I fix it so my app doesn't become invalidated every time it's copied? Note that the app still runs even though spctl fails. That said, should I even worry about this?

Comment: My guess would be that there's some metadata (xattrs or some such) being lost or encoded differently. But without any details, it's impossible to tell. What're the volume formats? How did you copy it? Have you tried a deep compare (`diff -r`)?.